# How to get field type list key value in custom block in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want key value in my twig template instead of list filed value.
I am trying with below code.
**content.field_alignment.0.key**

Answer (score 0):

I found answer of this question.

```
content.field_alignment['#items'].getValue()|first.value
```

Try like this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; you can adjust the format of the field in the display settings of the view mode for that content type to return the 'key' instead of the 'value' (structure > content types > *your content type* > Manage display).
In that scenario when you access the first element of the list like your example.

```
{{ content.field_alignment.0 }}
```

It should output the key.